# How to remove a relation in Juju after destroying one of the associated services?

Tags: juju

I am trying out Juju and while playing I created a service, Django, and then Mongodb. I associated them and then destroyed mongodb. Now my Django service is in an error status: agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "relation-broken"'. I have tried to destroy the relation with `juju destroy-relation python-django mongodb` to no avail. Mongodb still appears in juju status but in 'dying' state, it's been a few hours since I have destroyed it. I have not done any actual work on this service so I can destroy it and start again from scratch but while learning I would like to know if there is a cleaner way to solve that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the annoyingly "in hindsight" bit. It is always a good idea to remove relations before destroying services: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-destroy

Once a machine is in an error state, Juju will not process any hooks for that service - even ones to destroy it. That is to protect against potential data loss.
However there is a mechanism to return the machine to a responsive state:

```
juju resolved <machine identifier>
```

e.g.

```
juju resolved mongodb/0
```

This will re-enable the execution of hooks for that machine/service. Then it will be possible to:

```
juju destroy-relation mongodb django
juju destroy-service mongodb
juju destroy-service django
```

Comment: great, only by doing `juju resolved python-django/0` the status is now perfectly ok for this service and the mongodb service has disappeared! I would not do it on a prod environment but I wanted to try to see what would happen since the doc does not mention the situation :)

Comment: usually one would use 
  juju ssh <identifier>
to connect to machines that were in an error state and fix whatever the problem is. it seems odd that the mongodb disappeared to be honest